# Could someone tell me how matlab quat2eul operates?

Tags: matlab, rotations, quaternions

As in does it return euler angles with respect to intrinsic(local) or extrinsic(global)? The default order is ZYX.

Comment: You better have to look on the web. I found for example [this](https://itectec.com/matlab/matlab-quat2eul-conversion-sequence/). MathStackExchange is not the best place for questions like yours dealing with the implementation of a function of a very specific toolbox. This wouldn't be the case for more general questions dealing with Matlab implementation of general-purpose algorithms..

Comment: [this document](http://www.kostasalexis.com/frame-rotations-and-representations.html) should bring you some information.